# How to store Username and Password into a file in 2 void functions?

Tags: c++, void

I'm going to simplify my question... How would I implement an If/else statement or any statement that would take data the user enters from my createaccount function and verifies it against the login function? If the login does not match what is in the file "accounts.txt", it would not work and loops back to the mainmenu function.

```
 using namespace std;

    char mainMenu();
    void createAccount();
    void login();
    char bankingMenu();                 // Prototypes Declared Here
    void deposit();
    void withdraw();
    void displayBalance();
    void ShowTransHist(); // Gets transaction history from the file path string and display
int main()
{


    char choice;
    while (choice != 'q' || choice != 'Q')
    {
        choice = mainMenu();
        if (choice == 'q' || choice == 'Q') break;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 'l':
        case 'L':
            login();
            break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            createAccount();
            break;
        case 'v':
        case 'V':
            cout << "Thank you for using our bank and Future Computer Programmer ATM Machine! \nFor your continued support, we are offering 3% cash back on all debit purchases." << endl;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
char mainMenu() // Function to display the main menu, not banking menu
{
    char choice;
    cout << "Please select an option from the menu below:" << endl;
    cout << "l -> Login" << endl;
    cout << "c -> Create New Account" << endl;
    cout << "v -> View Promotions" << endl;
    cout << "q -> Quit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice: " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;

}
void createAccount() // Takes and stores users login information, username and password
{
   string username;
   string password;
   cout << "Please create a username";
   cin >> username;
   cout << "Please create a password";
   cin >> password;
   ofstream createaccount;
   createaccount.open("accounts.txt");
   createaccount << username << " " << password;
   createaccount.close();
   cout << "Information saved" << endl;

}
void login() // Takes information stored in create account
{
    string username;
    string password;
    cout << "Please enter your username";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Please enter your password";
    cin >> password;
    ifstream savedaccount;
    savedaccount.open("accounts.txt");
    savedaccount >> username >> password;
    savedaccount.close();
    cout << "Login successful";

}
```

Comment: *My problem lies with my login function at the bottom* doesn't explain what problem you are having with it.

Comment: I have to take the information the user enters in the createaccount function and read it into the login function using the file "account.txt"

Comment: Yes I did.  That doesn't explain what problem with that you are having.

Comment: Search for std::map. Teach yourself. It is much simpler container especially for this type of problem solving. A std::map has keys and every key has a value, and a key can't be duplicated(username) and every key has a value(password). Easy to insert, search, delete.. etc.

Comment: what can't you do? save to the file? read from the file? make sense of the content of the file? suggestion: separate your data `savedaccount >> username >>",">> password;`

Comment: I just didn't know how to get the file to separate the text between username and password, but I think Diego just answered it, i'll try it. I also need to create an if else statement, but not sure how to implement that, I'll experiment in a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure how to read from the file the 2 values a user enters for username and password, which the user creates in the createaccount function, and the login function would check if what the user enters matches what the file says.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to implement if/else in my login function...